# Azure AD : Getting a STS token for executing a shell script

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have Azure AD and linked with AWS accounts. I am using an Ec2 instance (AWS). I need to execute a shell script which fetches the AD Users and Groups and import it to AWS.

I am able to fetch the data using AZ CLI commands after logging in as my Azure AD user on that instance. I am aware the sessions will last for 3600 minutes only.  There is a setting in AWS where I can configure the secret and access key and access the resources via CLI. I want a similar thing for azure (if any).

Either, I need a permanent token or like an STS which generates only when the script is being called and fetches the data from AD.

I have the secret key/Tenant ID/Client ID, can someone lemme know how can I achieve that?

Comment: az login --service-principal -u CLIENT_ID -p CLIENT_SECRET --tenant TENANT_ID --allow-no-subscriptions.    This thing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get whole documentation how to build your type of the application, based on secured oauth flow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview